# Unable to catch MySqlException [Entity Framework WebAPI]

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Code looks like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

WebServer return 500 Intenal due to duplicate Key, but never entered catch block.
I want to know how to catch MySqlException at above code.

```
ExceptionMessage: "Duplicate entry 'TEST2' for key 'IX_User'"
ExceptionType: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException"

StackTrace: 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) 
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed) 
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) 
System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) 
System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()"
```

Comment: [Solved] MySqlException is InnerException.

Comment: catch(Exception e) { Exception mysqlE = e.GetBaseException();}

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by **SQLException** like this:

```
// your class code

try{
// do your work
}catch(SQLExcepetipn e){
// handle it
}
```

There is no MYSQL Exception class.

Comment: using MySql not sql. doesn't work. and c# not java ;;

Comment: oh man, MYSQL don't have MySQLException class, internally SQL HAndels these exeptions.

Comment: i have seen buddy, i am not providing you the answer of your code, i'm telling you these exception class will handle your exceptions, rather MYSQLException... may be there exist in C#, but a/c to mysql, there is no MySQLException class,

Comment: edited question.  Server Throw MySqlException. and MySql Connector have it.. thx anyway.

Comment: I've removed import statement. not its a logic not a code.. :)